# How can i backup and restore file on an azure website

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

I'm using Octopus deploy to deploy a site to azure.  I'm trying to backup a file before the deploy, then put it back after, and not sure of the best way to do it.

I don't think there's any azure powershell commands to access a website's filesystem, so my next thought is FTP which seems dirty since I then need to incorporate FTP creds into my deploy instead of just Azure subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like what you really want to do is prevent a specific file from being deleted/overwritten during deployment, and you're trying to do that by copying that file to a safe location during deploying, and then copying it back afterwards.

You can perform custom operations during deployment by creating your own custom deployment script ([detailed instructions here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script)).  That'll let you automatically copy the file to a temporary folder before the deployment, and then copy it back afterwards.